# NUnit won't run my unit tests; says that the test adapter is missing, but I did install it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, visual-studio-2019

I have a C# solution containing an NUnit test project. This project is refusing to run any tests; they are found by discovery but then I get these errors (among others) in the output window:

```
The active test discovery was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed
========== Test discovery aborted: 0 Tests found in 1.9 sec ==========
---------- Resuming previously aborted test discovery ----------
Test project Tests does not reference any .NET NuGet adapter. Test discovery or execution might not work for this project.
```

Now I did add that reference (NUnit3TestAdapter) but I still see this error. What's going on? Why won't my tests run? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: are you using NUnit 3 or Nunit 2? Are you running .net core or .net framework?

Comment: How did you add the reference? Were rebuild done?

Comment: This is .NET Framework v4.8 using NUnit 3. I added the reference via NuGet, and I did do a full clean and rebuild.

Comment: Can you share the csproj file?

Comment: @TerjeSandstrøm Sure, here you go! https://pastebin.com/uGppWa1z

Comment: Well that's weird. Mysteriously it started working again,,,

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. Installing 'NUnit3TestAdapter' nuget package in the UnitTest project fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you referred "nunit.framework.dll" in your test project

Comment: I have the NUnit and NUnit3TestAdapter nuget packages refernced, will those cover that requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `xunit.runner.visualstudio` package

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).